# Anybody ever see this weird windows cmd line directory, and have any idea what it means?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm a unix guy, I don't know much about windows networking, but I know DOS from 2.11, and this just looks like a bug, but maybe it means something.

H: is a mount to a shared drive. So is Z:, different mount.

```
H:\>dir
 Volume in drive H is SAN-Data
 Volume Serial Number is 0CB9-5031

 Directory of H:\

02/19/2014  08:57 AM    <DIR>          .
02/19/2014  08:57 AM    <DIR>          ..

 ...blah blah blah...



H:\>cd :

H:\:\>dir
 Volume in drive H is SAN-Data
 Volume Serial Number is 0CB9-5031

 Directory of H:\:

File Not Found

H:\:\>
```

Ain't that just a little weird?
And it doesn't do it on all network shared drives, just some.

```
Z:\>cd :
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Z:\>
```

Comment: What do the mounts point to ? There indeed seems to be a ":" directory on your H mount ?! I don't think it's possible on Windows, but on *nix, I believe it is.

Comment: I agree with Fred, there's a folder named `:` on that SAN volume the H: map is pointing to.

Comment: look under "naming conventions" colon is not allowed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know exactly what kind of san server it is, but I'm sure it's windows all the way down.

Comment: what if you do H:\>dir /ad /b<ENTER>    the /ad will show just directories but including hidden and /b will just list them cleanly. But I doubt it'll show it. that is weird.  It doesn't work on my network drive and I can't even do `md :` to make a directory called `:` it doesn't happen for me. that is  a strange thing you have there. be interesting if it shows up with `dir /ad /b`

Comment: @Stu yeah `:` isn't allowed there in windows but maybe it was created with another operating system(maybe a palm pc type thing pre smartphones). i've seen a folder with illegal chars in it, windows wouldn't let me delete it, and i'm not sure how it got created, maybe some bag or some device or something made it. But yeah you can get a folder with illegal chars created in another OS or maybe by a computer program, and then Windows can see it though can't handle it right. I had that on a usb stick I ended up formatting it to remove it though another OS might've removed it.

Comment: @barlop hunh. I didn't know that. I guess kudos to windows for not crashing horribly. although it's funny that it does try to play ball at all. Again I don't know what's on the end of that network share, but I guess somebody managed to do something illegal to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of how the command is being interpreted;  it's not about Windows networking.

It is completely possible -- and not even uncommon -- to have directory names in Windows that contain illegal characters.  The Windows APIs cannot handle these characters, so managing them through the GUI is near-impossible;  often you can't even rename to fix the bad characters.  To remediate such names, you have to use the command line or 3rd-party utilities like Unlocker.

In this case, what I think you're running into is a backup program that creates a folder named ":"   For whatever reason, backup programs seem often implicated in creating folder names with colons.

Search "colon directory name windows" and you will see plenty of mentions of same.

To ensure that the folder name really is just a colon, though, see what happens if you include quotes around it as a name, i.e.

```
CD ":"
```

or

```
CD "\:"
```

FWIW, another way that illegal names are created in Windows is simply by copying a folder structure from another source, which contains those names.  Windows generally does nothing to stop copying with the illegal names if you use a command like XCOPY, and will also allow you to copy a structure that results in path lengths longer than the ~255 characters that the Windows APIs can handle.

One last note -- some SAN devices allow the loading of more than one namespace.  This means that multiple names are stored with each entry, so that you will generally see the stored 8.3 name as well as the full long name, and could also have, say, Mac namespace that stores a name compatible with Mac naming requirements.  Without knowing more about the SAN, I can't advise you what is in use, but it poses another possibility.  You can see some of this if you just do the listing to include the 8.3 names, which in Windows is

```
DIR /X
```

Comment: interesting bunch of tests. When I do cd ":" from the root (h:) it goes there. If I again go back to the root of h: and try cd "\:" it goes there too. But then if while I'm in h:\:\ I then try cd "\:" I get a "The system cannot find the drive specified." which seems odd that the current directory would affect the parsing of the new fully qualified path. aha! if I'm in h:\:\ and then I do cd \: without the quotes it works. windows is weird.